# Best way for getting a value through href

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink, href

This is my  link

```
<a href="#popup-1"> Click Me </a>
```

and it has a corresponding div that will pop up and it's code looks like this.

```
 <div id="popup-1"> I'm the pop up</div>
```

Is there a method in which I could pass up a php value from the href to the div?

I already tried this one. `<a href="#popup-1?a=$new"> Click Me </a>`

Is there any other way to get the value?

Comment: u need to pass data from PHP to JS via HTML node ?

Comment: `<a href="#popup-1?a=<?php echo $new ?>"> Click Me </a>`

Comment: Yes. I already tried that one. If I do that it would no longer go to the div.

Comment: Let us know which popup plugin you are using.

Comment: I think there isn't any plugin. It's just a div. After I click the "Click Me" It will automatically go to the div in which will display some data.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
<?php 
$new ="i am here";
?>
<a href="#popup-1" data-input="<?php echo $new ?>"> Click Me </a> 

 <div id="popup-1"> I'm the pop up</div>
<Script>

$('a').click(function () {
    console.log($('a').data("input"));
    $("#popup-1").html($('a').data("input"));
});

</Script>
```

Comment: How do I get the value from this jquery to php?

Comment: use ajax or create form and direct submit on click of anchor depends on your ui and use.

Comment: Which is much easier? I need to get the value from the href and use it on div but I don't have any ideas on how to do it.

Comment: this answer is doing that.to display in div why you need to send it to php until and unless you want some other info.

Comment: what is your main objective.

Comment: I think we are having a misunderstanding. Sorry about that. My main objective is get the php value that was passed through the href then to the div. I need the value so that I could get new the values from the database and display it on the div.

Comment: may be i'm not getting.you simply want $new value to show in div or not because your question is saying this only,and answer is doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="clickMe" data-value = "<?php echo $new?>"> Click Me </div> 
div id="popup-1"></div>

//jQuery
$(document).on('click', '#clickMe', function(){
var text = $('#clickMe').attr('data-value');
$('#popup-1').text(text);
});
```

Comment: How do I get the value from this jquery to php?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#popup-1" class="clickMe"> Click Me </a>
<div id="php_value"> <?php echo $php_value; ?> <div>
<div id="popup-1"> I'm the pop up</div>


    $(".clickMe").click(function(){    
    var text = $("#php_value").html();
     $("#popup-1").html(text);
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

`<a href ="#popup-1?a="<?php echo $new ?>">Click Me </a>`

Comment: Ok wait a second, you want to pass certain value from that href to the div when you click on it? You can store the value from PHP in data attribute and then display that in div with little jQuery.

Comment: Ok. How do i do that? I don't know much about jquery.

Comment: Ill add another answer